# Trying to make an amplifier to work

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier

I am designing a headphone amplifier around the IC TL074. I have this circuit so far.

[image]

This circuit is almost good but the sound I see at the output is slightly distorted. I think it has to do with the cross over between the output transistors T1/Q1 and T2/Q2.

Then I tried to make it an AB amplifier by converting the circuit to...

[image]

And now I have no sound at the output.

These were my problems:

1. I was not sure if I could direct couple the op amp and the base of the transistors, so I have added an electrolytic, C2 and C3 (220uF x 16V) there.
2. I am not sure if I have calculated R27, R28, R29 and R31 correctly.

I have no sound at all.

- VCC = 9V
- VCC_1 = 4.5V
- load = headphone 32 ohms

Any ideas?

Comment: What is VCC_1 connected to?

Comment: he would have to use an offset trim circuit @VCC_1 but they should be independent so that the dc offset can be adjusted individually.

Comment: So what is the dc supply voltage to the op amps? What is the dc supply voltage to the output transistors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a \$9\:\text{V}\$ battery, you have to be aware of the fact that the battery has a series internal resistance of about \$2\:\Omega\$. This isn't the most important detail. But it it is a reason why you will want to parallel the battery with a capacitor. It needs one. Also, while the \$9\:\text{V}\$ battery might deliver an average of \$100\:\text{mA}\$ or more, it won't do that for a long time and the voltage will definitely droop pretty rapidly under a heavier load. So that's one detail to keep in mind -- (1) short life under heavy load, (2) drooping voltage over its life, and (3) the need for a capacitor to *help out* a bit. I mention this first because it's easiest to understand, not because it is the most important detail.

---

The next easy point to make is that adding resistors and diodes to bias your output BJT quadrants (either channel) is not so good. As the opamp drives the signal upward, this lowers the voltage drop across the upper resistor, lowering the current available through it, lowering the available current from which the upper quadrant BJT can source its needed base current, and all this happens right when the upper quadrant BJT ***needs*** an increasing base current to do its work. Using resistors here means either using unnecessarily low resistor values (waste of power), higher sink/source capability from the opamp itself, and a reduced range of *useful* voltage swings at the output.

---

Next, you want your NFB to source from the output, itself. Not the output of the opamp. Making the output of the opamp follow your input has a nice look to it, but it's not what you actually need. You want the output of the entire amplifier system to follow the input (with gain.) Not the output of the opamp, itself. Different things.

---

You won't like the following idea because it's ... more complicated. Even so, it still doesn't deal with dead-short protection/current limiting that could be added. But it does deal with *some* important details to make it work. Use this as a source of ideas to examine and consider, at least.

The following is arranged for a \$32\:\Omega\$ headphone. Different headphones will require some changes. (And if you wanted to use an \$8\:\Omega\$ speaker, instead, you'd want to divide the values of \$R_1\$ through \$R_6\$ by a factor of about 2 or more.)

Note the big capacitor across the battery. Also note the use of two potentiometers. \$R_{14}\$, together with \$R_{15}\$, sets the quiescent current.

The purpose of \$R_{15}\$ is to adjust things so that you get a "parabolic" behavior of the VBE multiplier with varying currents through it. But it isn't critical to you. So just remove/bypass \$R_{15}\$ if you want to. It won't hurt much, at all. It's just there so that if someday you want to come back to this little detail, you can. (Or keep it, but don't worry about its setting, reserved for later playing around.)

\$R_{14}\$, once \$R_{15}\$ is ignored for now, is what sets the quiescent current. You can measure this by placing a voltmeter across \$R_1\$ and measuring the voltage there when there is no signal applied. You will want to waste about 5%-10% of the maximum power, quiescently. The voltage you want to find across \$R_1\$ will be something like this:

$$V_1\ge 5\%\cdot\frac{R_1}{R_\text{SPKR}}\cdot\frac{\left(V_\text{CC}-4\:\text{V}\right)^2}{V_\text{CC}}$$

So just apply your voltmeter to \$R_1\$ and adjust \$R_{14}\$ until you see that figure on the meter. It will be in millivolts.

I've selected a rail to rail opamp that is not too expensive, comes in dual packages (LT1801), and is a decent opamp. Feel free to substitute. But one of the critical criteria for the opamp is that its output can reach close to the negative rail (ground.) (The positive output limit isn't as important.) Do note that large capacitor across the battery. You probably want something big there. Not critical. But make it as large as you can afford.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWD7bh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've also kept the gain you had specified. Feel free to adjust the ratio of \$R_{19}\$ and \$R_{20}\$ per your needs, though.

The dissipation in \$Q_1\$ and \$Q_2\$ will likely be okay even for TO-92 packaging. But if you decide to shoot for an \$8\:\Omega\$ speaker and adjust \$R_1\$ through \$R_6\$ and use the fuller volume possible, then they may need to become TO-220 packaged devices, instead. Otherwise, they may get too hot (though the battery won't last all that long then, either.)

The green boxes highlight the two quadrant driver sections and the blue section is the VBE multiplier. \$R_{11}\$ will supply a near-constant current that is sufficient for these quadrants' base drive.

Comment: Hi there, I have tried your circuit and I am seeing exactly the same problem as mine. I do not have an oscilloscope right now but I have used an iPad app to capture the output from the headphone and what I see is the wave a little bit [distorted near the peak and valley](https://imgur.com/a/emeZ6bQ). This happens until 3/4 of the volume. From that up, the wave [distorts completely](https://imgur.com/a/WixYTBM). By the way, I adjust the trimpots and they make no difference at all. What purpose they serve?

Comment: @SpaceDog That circuit does work. It's been built. But it does require some tinkering since these BJTs are not matched at all. (That's one reason for so many resistors.) The pot in the \$Q_5\$ collector can probably just be set midway and forgotten for now. The other pot has to be adjusted, as I wrote (\$V_1\$.)

Comment: @SpaceDog Also, you do need to use an opamp of the type I described. I also set the amplifier to a fixed gain, which may not be appropriate in some signal circumstances. While testing, apply a smaller signal to start out and see what the output signal looks like (after setting \$V_1\$ as suggested, of course.) You can always set \$V_1\$ higher, too. So try doubling the value or tripling it and see if that helps. (As a debugging step.)

Comment: Hi, again, thanks for all your help but it seems impossible to find this LT1800 or even the quad version LT1802 on my country in Europe. I am able to find it on Sweden and other countries but it will cost me €30 (~USD $36) including shipping!!!! Do you know any other op amp I can use instead? Preferably DIP because I want to breadboard it fist... :) thanks again

Comment: @SpaceDog Wow! Here, that thing is perhaps $2 or $3? And it isn't unobtainium. I wonder what would happen if I just shipped you one free? Anyway, I mentioned the specifications. It MUST be able to reach close to the negative rail. It doesn't have to reach so close to the positive rail. I can't recommend a specific one without knowing what you can get there. I had NO IDEA that an LT1800 would be so difficult and expensive to you. So any recommendations risk the same. You tell me what you can easily get and I can look, though.

Comment: Would you be willing to send me two LT1800? I can pay you the ICs plus shipping using paypal or something.

Comment: @SpaceDog Sure. I'd be happy to do that. Digikey is showing them at $2.82 each in 1s. I could probably use some, myself. What kind of packaging are you interested in? And how will we make contact? (We could jump into a chat somewhere I suppose.)

Comment: I would like to thank you very much but I finally found a small store on my country where I was able to find it for $7 including shipping. Thanks for your availability.

Comment: @SpaceDog Sounds good. Let me know how that works.

Answer (score 4):

There are some issues here for you to address:

[image]

1. Keep in mind we can only see any picture you post here with 640 pixels wide maximum.  Lay out your schematic to not waste horizontal space.  The opamps could have been much closer to the output stage transistors, for example.  Remember that you are asking volunteers for a favor.

   VCC_1 needs to be about ½ the supply voltage in this design.  That is your internal signal quiescent level.  Getting that right and low noise is important, but it is not shown.

   Vcc needs to be large, like 24 V or so.  The TL07x opamps need several volts headroom at each end.  They are no good for 5 V operation, for example.  You generally want to use ±12 V (24 V total) at least with these opamps.

   The deadband due to the double emitter follower output stage is a obvious source of distortion.  There is about 1.4 V range coming out of the opamps that isn't going to the output.  That could be a large fraction of the signal into small headphones.  It is no surprise this result in highly distorted and bad sound.

   A quick hack to deal with the deadband is to include it in the feedback loop.  Instead of taking the feedback from the opamp output, take it from what you really want to control, which is the driver stage output.  With feedback around the deadband, the opamp will try to "jump over" the deadband quickly.  This won't be perfect, but good enough for basic operation.  I vaguely remember that the TL07x can slew about 8 V/µs, so the little glitch at crossover should be small.

   Considering you need the opamp to jump over the deadband as fast as possible, don't slow it down by using the feedback loop to add low pass filtering.  If you want low pass filtering, add it in front of the opamp.

   If the opamp is unstable after including the output drivers within the feedback loop, allow it to have some gain instead of first trying to slow it down.  You currently have a gain of 3.8, so maybe no deliberate compenstation cap is required.  Try it and see.

   The input caps are backwards.  Presumably the average level is ground at left, and half the supply at right.

   22 µF for the input caps is absurd.  With 18 kΩ in series, the high pass filter rolloff is 400 mHz.  That will take a long time to settle.  Just 1 µF gives you 9 Hz rolloff with 18 kΩ.  That's much more suitable for audio.  Now you can use a ceramic and not have to deal with the polarity and lifetime issues of electrolytics.  You need to pick a ceramic that doesn't exhibit piezo effects, and that isn't too non-linear with voltage.  One thing that helps with the latter is to get caps rated for more voltage than you need.  The lower capacitance again helps with this.  For example, 1 µF 50 V caps made with the right ceramic are more appropriate than the electrolytic caps you show.

   220 µF for the output caps may not be enough.  You didn't say what the impedance of the headphones are, but if they are 8 Ω, then the high pass filter rolloff is 90 Hz.  Conversely, to get 20 Hz, the headphones need to be 36 Ω.  At the least, check that this is all what you intended.

Comment: THANKS for all the info but I have some questions... 1) just click on the picture and it will enlarge...   2) sorry about that, VCC_1 is half VCC... 3) I am using a 9V battery...   6) do you mean C19 and C20?...   7) the op amp is not unstable and the volume increased after including the driver output in the feedback loop... 8) ok, thanks for the info.... 9) thanks I will replace them. ... 10) the headphones are 32 ohms.............. just one final question: do I need to bias the transistor like a classical Class AB Biasing with diodes?

Comment: @space: 1) Right.  It would be nice not to have to.  Note how I could make a good chunk of your schematic readable right in the answer with a little cropping and filtering. 6) Yes.  Your double emitter follower drivers are OK if the distortion (with them in the feedback loop) is OK.

Answer (score 3):

Try extending the local feedback loop around the op-amp to include the push pull output: -

[image]

This will give some improvement and will probably work better when the output transistors are biased as per your 2nd picture (but you will need to use low value emitter resistors in each transistor to set the bias correctly).

Comment: ok. I have converted the circuit to what you say, without any resistors or diodes on the final stage. The sound is now louder but the problem is the same, that is the wave slightly distorted. Cross-over problem on the output transistors. How do I bias the output transistors correctly to get rid of this cross-over? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SpaceDog the output cross over distortion should be reduced quite a lot with the circuit like this. Please check your findings. However, with 1 kohm bias resistors on the bases I'd be thinking about 10 ohm resistors in each emitter. Try that and see what improvement you get.

Comment: just out of curiosity, why is that 10 ohm resistor necessary?

Comment: The resistor in each emitter prevents (or rather largely avoids) thermal runaway and asymmetrical distortion. It's a form of local negative feedback.

Comment: when you say a 10 ohm resistor on each emitter you are talking ONE resistor between T1/Q1 and ONE resistor between T2/Q2, right?

Comment: For each transistor, insert a resistor in series with the emitter as per R9 and R10 on [this example circuit](http://m.blog.hu/ga/gazz/image/poweramp/simple-100-w-power-amp.jpg)

Comment: I just wanted to say that I'd never seen extending the feedback loop of an opamp to include other stages like this and it was one of those "Woah!..wait, duh!" moments. Really neat, thanks for sharing this.

Answer (score 2):

Thumbs up for taking an exercise in classic analog audio amp design :-)

The BC5xx transistors are IMO a little too weak for a power amplifier, albeit just for headphones. I'd use something with with a permissible current of 1A+, and your design would probably use another stage as drivers to the power transies. Or just use darlingtons. Which expands the design towards a proper audio power amp in class AB, see Mr. Jonk's fine answer.

Your second version of the design already contains rudimentary "quiescent current biasing" for the output totem - bravo, you're heading in the right direction. Note that the plain resistors to VCC and GND are not optimal for biasing. At maximum amplitude, where you need to drive the transies hardest towards the PSU rails, these resistors provide least current. This will result in clipping. Constant current sources would be better. Maybe based on current mirrors. And you could steer the mirrors from some earlier stage in the amp, with variable signal... there are lots of possibilities and the design quickly gets complicated.

If you're adventurous, take a look at MOSFET's. Their "gate threshold voltage" will be a pain though, at your reasonably low PSU rail voltages. There are cheap MOSFET's for use in CPU VRM's (buck SMPS) and some such, in SO8 or TO252 and similar packages. They have just about the right Vds for your application and their Vgsth is somewhat bearable. Note that they're "switching" devices - their Rdson when fully open is in milliohms and their permissible current may be about 100A, but beware of their SOAR = they have a pretty limited dissipatable power. Also their input gate capacitance is non-trivial (nanoFarads), not sure if an op-amp would be willing to drive that directly. And they're *fast*, optimized for switching, and may be eager to oscillate if biased just above Vgsth in a linear fashion. I'd probably use some bipolar op-amp to drive such FET's, NE5532 comes to mind (if not discrete driver transistors). I've never tried this, so I may be kidding :-) And even with MOSFET's, you should take feedback from the discrete power totem's very output (as others have suggested).

An oscilloscope would help while playing with these - which is a pretty universal and expensive advice in anything to do with electronics :-)

I understand that your mission is to learn something from this exercise - and I applaud that. If you want to learn more about the principles of the various stages in an op-amp / audio power amp, I suggest a book called ["Designing Analog Chips" by Hans Camenzind](http://www.designinganalogchips.com/). Available for download in PDF from the author's website. Interesting reading and not painfully mathematical. I've learned about the book here at SA (thanks). In your circuit, you could employ several of the op-amp building blocks mentioned in the book.

If the point really was to cobble together a phones amp quickly for some misc application, I'd use a TEA2025 (EOL, perhaps still available at some shops as overstock) or some such. These linear amps are admittedly getting out of the vogue, in favour of class D devices...

Comment: thanks for all the info. I really love analog amplifiers! I dream of building something with tubes one day ... I love to learn. Said that, your answer is amazing. thanks. I am a little broke now but I will try to get an oscilloscope as soon as possible even if it is one with tubes... :)

Comment: @spacedog entirely welcome. These feedbackey audio things make great toys. I was in your shoes about 20 years ago. My first 'scope that I used while playing with discrete-based audio amps was something tube-based (scrapped from someone's lab at the time). The 'scope had about 5 MHz of bandwidth = plenty good enough for audio. As for tube-based amps... not my pot of tea. The rail voltages are dangerous. With the money from my first job, I built an all-discretes power amp with "fully complementary" topology, on a DIY PCB... and I learned a lot about troubleshooting in a complex feedback loop :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using your second circuit,

a) get rid of C2 and C3

b) connect your op amp feedback to points A and B as Andy aka shows.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to the biasing....

To reduce crossover distortion still further you could try adding a schottky diode (for example BAT85) in series with D3 and D5 to increase the biasing between the transistor bases by a further 0.3 or 0.4 volts. If you do this make sure you add 10R emitter resistors.

Other good suggestions include increasing Vcc, taking the negative feedback from the output, removing C2 & C3, increase the current handling capabilities of the output transistors (eg use BC337 and BC327).

With the extra diode and 10R emitter resistors the quiescent current should be about 0.2V/10R = 20mA.